# How I can find slash "/" into html with regular expression in Dreamweaver?

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I try to find a slash in this code with `[\/][^]` expression:

```
<td>12321/213213</td>
```

but it not work (...

image how it work here:

[image]

Comment: Why the `[^]` ? Why not simply `\/` ? Is that a Dreamweaver specific thing ?

Comment: which slash do you want to find?  the one in the `</td>` tag or the one in the text?

Comment: no, isn't...I can use only / but then finding / in tag (

Comment: Sam, I need replace / between numbers, but not in tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a regular expression for this one time find/replace, than the following regex works:

```
\b\/\b
```

the `\b` means **word boundary**

[tested in rubular](http://rubular.com/r/UMfvIAokLn)